# display a Histogram using function

Tags: c++

How to display a histogram of a generated matrix

if the program asks the user to enter any character (symbol) E.g. (#,*,&....)
and then displays this character according to the elements of matrix arr[][]

for example if the elements of matrix arr[2][2] are : 3 6 2 1
the histogram will be in this form:

3 ***

6 ******

2 **

1 *

i tried to do this but of course it doesn`t work

```
for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<setw(4)<<character;
    }

}
```

here is the program

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;


int main()
 {
int i, j,rows,cols;
int arr[5][5];
cout<< "enter rows and cols : ";
cin>> rows>> cols;


for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        cout<< "enter elements "<<": ";
        cin>> arr[i][j];
    }
}

cout<<" Please enter the display character: ";
cin>>character;
cout<< "\n Histogram :"<< endl;
 for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
    {
        cout<<arr[i][j]<<setw(4)<<character;
    }

}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: Explain what you've tried, and what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

While printing each element you could print the same number of `*`'s

You could implement a function to print required number of `*`'s.

```
   for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
       {
         cout <<arr[i][j];
         print_some_stars(arr[i][j]);
         cout<<endl;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Alright, but the program does not ask to print stars only, it based on the symbol enterd by the user

Comment: print_some_stars(arr[i][j]);   // error :argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type " int(*)[5]"

Comment: @moonlight i have not written `print_some_stars(int)` for you.You have to write one for yourself to print `stars` or some other character.